# Проверить, что в числе ровно одна цифра «9»

Tags: c

Ввести целое число и определить, верно ли, что в нём ровно одна цифра «9». Язык Си, код с помощью циклов(условие). Что я делаю не так? Код работает

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main(void)
{
    int n, lft, lst, count;
    _Bool flag = 1;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n)
    {
        lst = n%10;
        lft = n/10;
        count = 0;
        while (lft)
        { 
            if (lst == 9)
            { 
                flag = 0;
                break;
                count++;
            }
            lft/=10;
        }
        n/=10; 
    }
    if (flag = 1 && count!=0 && count>1) 
        printf("NO");
    else
        printf("YES");
  
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Название вопрос должно исключительно включать тему проблемы или её текст, а уже сами подробности должны быть **в вопросе**. Вопрос можно отредактировать кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1460149/edit).

Comment: Какие-то замудрёные циклы. Можно проще: `#include <stdlib.h> ... int count = 0;
while(n)
{
count += abs(n%10) == 9;
n /= 10;
}
if (count == 1) printf("YES");`

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: если код работает, то все делаешь так

Comment: цикл `while (lft)  {` поменяйте на `do{ .. }while(lft);`

Comment: Если будет проще - переводите число в строку, идете по символам и считаете количество символов `9`.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще правильный и красивый код написал wololo в своем комментарии.
Но если говорить о вашей реализации, то есть недостатки:
Оператор `if()` в конце отрабатывает не все варианты результатов. Упростите его от обратного - вывод "YES" только если `count == 1`

```
// вместо вот этого
 if (flag = 1 && count!=0 && count>1) 
        printf("NO");
    else
        printf("YES");
// сделайте проще
 if (count == 1) 
        printf("YES");
    else
        printf("NO");
```

Ошибка в логике - вы ввели число, а оно равно нулю. Цикл не отработал ни одной итерации и замудреный оператор `if()` в конце выдаст "YES". Но поскольку count в начале программы не инициализирован, если повезет и он будет больше единицы, то выдаст правильный ответ. Но это просто совпадение.

```
    int n, lft, lst, count;
    _Bool flag = 1;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n)
    {
    }
    if (flag = 1 && count!=0 && count>1) 
        printf("NO");
    else
        printf("YES");
```

Примерно такая же проблема со вложенным циклом. Если число из 1 цифры, то `lft == 0` и цикл не запустится. То же самое для последней цифры - она не проверится. Т.е. для числа `911` - `11` проверятся, а `9` - нет.

```
        lft = n/10;
        while (lft)
        { }
```

Внутри оператора `if()` - `count++;` никогда не выполняется. т.к. перед ним стоит `break;` Т.е. вы ничего не подсчитываете.

```
            if (lst == 9)
            { 
                flag = 0;
                break;  // вот здесь выход из цикла
                count++;  // а это никогда не выполняется
            }
```

Логика обнуления `count` очень странная. Даже если бы вы подсчитывали что-то в операторе `if()`, то тут же во внешнем цикле обнуляли все ваши подсчеты. В итоге на выходе count будет равно единице, только если самая левая цифра будет равна 9. Переменную `count` нужно обнулить один раз - в начале программы `int count = 0;`, иначе теряется смысл счетчика.

```
while (n) // проход по всем цифрам в числе
    {
        count = 0;  // а вот тут обнуление всего, что вы раньше посчитали
        while (lft) // проход по остатку цифр в числе
        {   
           // подсчет девяток
        }
    }
```

Вообще непонятно зачем вложенные циклы. Сейчас получается вы проходите по числу `n*log n` раз. Например для числа `999` вы насчитаете 6 девяток.

Comment: *"правильный и красивый код"* - в этой задаче отсутствует необходимость что-то делить или считать остаток от деления

Comment: @user7860670 Почему? Это один из способов решения задачи. Пример wololo занял 6 строк кода и без использования дополнительной памяти. На мой взгляд - правильно и красиво. Можно решить через строки.